# Stack margin text in ConTeXt

Tags: context, marginpar, context-mkiv

If I try the following in ConTeXt:

```
\starttext 

text text\inmargin{this is a note.} text text\inmargin{Another note.}

\input knuth 

text text\inmargin[stack=yes]{this is a note.} text text\inmargin[stack=yes]{Another note.}

\input knuth 

text text\inmargin[stack=yes]{this is a note. Now longer.} text text\inmargin[stack=yes]{Another note.}

\input knuth 

\stoptext
```

then it only works for short notes. For longer notes I found the suggestion to use `stack=continue`, but I could not make that work either.

[image: output]

So my question is: How to make it work with floating (not overlapping) text [edit: in MKIV]?

EDIT1: It only does not work in MKIV , MKII  is fine

(`ConTeXt  ver: 2011.05.18 18:04 MKIV  fmt: 2012.5.8  int: english/english`)

(`ConTeXt  ver: 2011.05.18 18:04 MKII  fmt: 2012.5.11  int: english/english`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ConTeXt MK II, add `\setupinmargin[stack=yes]` to your preamble, e.g.:

```
\setupinmargin[stack=yes]
\starttext
    This is some text.\inmargin{This is in the margin.}
    This is some more text.\inmargin{This text is also in the margin.}
\stoptext
```

For more available options, see [this article about setupinmargin](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupinmargin) at the ConTeXt Wiki.

If you are using ConTeXt Mk IV, you may use `\margintext` in place of `\inmargin` and also add `\setupinmargin[stack=yes]` to the preamble, e.g.:

```
\setupinmargin[stack=yes]
\starttext
    This is some text.\margintext{This is in the margin.}
    This is some more text.\margintext{This text is also in the margin.}
\stoptext
```

Comment: This does not work either and I would have been confused if it would have. However, it gave me another clue and I updated the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer. See if this works.

Comment: It does work now. It breaks 'location=outer', but that is a different story... :(