# Stack margin text in outer margin in ConTeXt Mk IV

Tags: margins, context, context-mkiv, marginnote

I try to stack marginals with ConTeXt Mk-IV. In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55350/stack-margin-text-in-context) a possible solution was given. The solution works fine, but it turns out that the `location=outer` parameter does not work any more.

Please consider the following example:

```
\setupinmargin[stack=yes,location=outer]

\starttext 

text text\margintext{this is a note.} text text\margintext{Another note.}

\input knuth 

text text\margintext{this is a note.} text text\margintext{Another note.}

\input knuth 

text text\margintext{this is a note. Now longer.} text text\margintext{Another note.}

\input knuth 

\stoptext
```

It works fine in Mk-II (which is not an option for me). It disregards `location=outer` in Mk-IV.

If I replace now the `\margintext` macros with `\inouter`, it breaks the stacking in Mk-IV, but works in Mk-II.

Is there a solution that allows stacking, but keeps the marginals in the outer margin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the command `\definemargindata` it works as expected:

```
\setuppagenumbering [alternative=doublesided] % outer makes little sense otherwise
\definemargindata [margintext]
    [
      location=outer,
         align=flushleft,
         stack=continue, % or yes
    ]

\starttext

text text\margintext{this is a note.} text text\margintext{Another note.}

\input knuth 

text text\margintext{this is a note.} text text\margintext{Another note.}

\input knuth 

text text\margintext{this is a note. Now longer.} text text\margintext{Another note.}

\input knuth 

\stoptext
```

Comment: I updated everything with TeX Live Utility and it shows `ConTeXt  ver: 2011.05.18 18:04 MKIV  fmt: 2011.8.9  int: english/english`, but the notes are still on top of each other for your example on my computer.

Comment: Your context is too old, you need to update. I recommend [ConTeXt Standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone). My example works with the current version.